# To do or to have

Tags: grammar

I spoke this sentence while in a discussion, and something didn't sound right:

> Actions have consequences but so *do* inactions.

Later I thought what could be correct way of saying it.

Is this right?

> Actions have consequences but so *have* inactions.

Which of the two, if any, is correct?

Comment: No; the correct way would be to use a singular for _inaction_. After all, inaction is a state and not an event, so it doesn't really have a plural. So, _Actions have consequences, and so does inaction._ Saying _and so has inaction_ is less likely, at least in the U.S., where _have_ in the sense of 'possess' is normally not inverted with the subject.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that there is an implied phrase at the end. *Actions have consequences, but so does inaction [have consequences].* You can think of it that way. The word *do* here is a helper verb. Consider the difference: *he has* versus *he does have*. The latter is more emphatic.

Comment: Beat you to it!

Comment: The idiom *so does X* can be used with any verb - for example: "*Actions create consequences, but so do inactions.*" The idiom does not change when the verb happens to be *have*.

Comment: @JohnLawler Would it be okay if I produced an answer? I think your first comment answered his question almost completely, if not completely... but it wouldn't hurt for this question to have an answer.

Comment: John, ktm5124 and Michael, your comments together create the perfect answer, in my opinion. One helps explain the other. Only thing I'm not sure I understand is, _have in the sense of possess is normally not inverted with the subject_. Can someone explain this bit?

Comment: @JohnLawler nice answer, can you elaborate a little on what this means, "is normally not inverted with the subject." thanks

Comment: [Subject-Auxiliary Inversion](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+subject+auxiliary+inversion) reverses the order of the subject noun phrase and the first auxiliary verb. It occurs in questions (_You have finished ~ Have you finished?_), for instance. But in US English, _have_ meaning 'possess' is not an auxiliary and doesn't invert. Americans understand people who say _Have you the time?_ but they understand them not to be American  English speakers, who'd say _Do you have the time?_ with [_Do_-Support](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+do+support).

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler answered your question in his first comment. But, I would like to think that I added a tiny drop of clarity. Thus, I will be so bold as to create an answer.

> Actions have consequences, but so does inaction [have consequences].

I included the expansion in brackets, as it might make more sense grammatically. Might I also suggest a dramatic way of saying it?

> Actions have consequences, but so does the failure to act.

Comment: The "expansion" is the repeated material deleted by the rule of [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+conjunction+reduction).

Answer (score 1):

I think several things may have made you feel the sentence did not sound right:

First and foremost, what follows "so" in those constructions has to be an auxiliary or a verb like "be," which does not require an auxiliary. In traditional British English, where "have/has" do not require an auxiliary in the present simple tense, their inversion will be acceptable.

This is taken from Swan's "Practical English Usage" (3rd edition):

[image: So - auxiliary]

Therefore, in the present simple tense "do/does" are always correct after "so," and "has/have" (as main verbs) are only partially acceptable in British English (notice the example *I have a headache. So **have** I* above.)

Another thing that might be creating a sense of unbalance -- though this may be subject to different opinions -- is the plural of "actions" and the singular of "inaction." In a structure like the one at issue, I'd prefer plural-plural, or singular-singular. "Action" can be used as a non-count noun, synonymous with "acting," but "actions" sounds better. "Inaction" is only a non-count noun. Then, the best solution would perhaps be to choose a pair of plural opposites, like "actions and omissions." These two words appear as antonyms on many very well-written pages on the Internet, like this one: https://pages.stolaf.edu/ein/themes/acts-and-omissions/

Finally, the opposites already show contrast, so I think the use of "but" may be redundant and inappropriate. I'd say:

- *Actions have consequences, **and** so do omissions.*

Comment: 'Omissions' is not specific enough to be used as the antonym of 'actions'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In philosophy and religion, for example, they are usually presented as antonyms. The plural also contributes to creating balance between the two terms.

Comment: I know the terms 'sins of c/omission' but not 'sins of action'. I'm happy with the string 'failure to act'. But I'm not familiar with 'omission' being used in place of 'failure to act'.

Comment: What does all this have to do with the question, which about using *have* vs. *do*?

Comment: @michael.hor257k There's no doubt about "do" being the correct choice. We are just discussing better ways of putting the idea, if you don't mind.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Here's just one of the many examples where those two words can be found as opposites: https://pages.stolaf.edu/ein/themes/acts-and-omissions/ You commit actions, and incur omissions.

Comment: I'll retract the downvote if you amend your answer to include the reference (though it would be better to include a more mainstream example on ELU). However, as @michael.hor257k says, this is not really an answer to the question. Note that John Lawler gives an elegant solution (rather than an answer) _in a comment_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Done! I've seized the opportunity to recast my answer as a whole.

Comment: Are you saying that 'I'm hot.' ... 'So am I.' (non-auxiliary usage) is unacceptable in the US? That's how your sentence 1b now reads. But note Swan's extension: 'The same structure is possible ...'.  In 'BrE', 'John has a cricket bat, and so have I' is probably more idiomatic than the 'do' version (probably far more idiomatic in the US).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Come on, you very well know I didn't mean to say that. The verb "be" acts as its own auxiliary in "I'm hot." In AmE, "have" does not act as its own auxiliary in "I have a headache." Just in case, by auxiliary I mean the verb that is placed before the subject in interrogative sentences and to which "not" is added in the negative.

Comment: Your use of 'auxiliary' is unacceptable. Back to -1.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry if I hurt your feelings. It was teachers' jargon. You can find some more of that on the Internet: https://detachments.dreamwidth.org/5693.html : *And be, unlike the other auxiliaries and indeed any other verb, acts as its own auxiliary in negative statements and yes-or-no questions : They are ready. They are not ready. Are they ready?* I have edited my answer to avoid any confusion, but you may keep your downvote unchanged. I really don't care. I just want to be a helper, not an obstacle.

Comment: What I read there is 'The verbs be, do, and have are unique in English in that each is [has roles as] both a full verb as well as an auxiliary verb.' [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/be) clearly divides the main verb [usages of] 'be' from the auxiliary. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be) is at least as clear. / Saying 'I just want to be a helper, not an obstacle.' doesn't sit well with 'The verb "be" acts as its own auxiliary in "I'm hot." ' It's a link verb / copula there, not an auxiliary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth At this stage, I'm sure anyone knowledgeable in English (as most ELU members are supposed to be) understands what I wrote (or rewrote after some revision) in my answer above. However, your purposefully twisted interpretation of my words presents me as someone ignorant of the most elementary rules of the language, which I certainly am not. I will devote my time to **helping** somewhere else, while you do your **other job** here. Adieu, ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You might want to read StoneyB's comment here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124421/examples-that-show-imperative-be-is-a-special-verbauxiliary-verb, which endorses the point of view you condemned as unacceptable: "(2) The current orthodoxy in fact holds that the copular use is 'auxiliary', too: 'auxiliary' has been redefined to mean essentially 'exhibits the NICE properties', and is not restricted to catenating constructions."

Comment: You'd better do something to dispel the confusion, then. 'The same structure is possible with non-auxiliary _be_ ... "I was tired" ...' from Swan and your own 'has to be an auxiliary or a verb like "be," '.